# Memcached listen on selected interfaces

Tags: memcached

I am setting up Memcached on a Debian server that has two interfaces - eth0 (public) and eth1 (private).

I want Memcached to listen on both eth1 and lo (loopback) so that it can be accessed even if the private network goes down but NOT eth0 (public).

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/memcached) for memcached I understand that the `-l` option can take only one IP address. I thought of using UNIX sockets for local connections but the man page says

> -s 
>      Unix socket path to listen on (**disables network support**).

The only other method I know is to block connections via eth0 using IPTables. Is there any other solution that does not make use of the firewall?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not as convenient as listing an interface and getting all of its bound addresses, and it requires knowing all the addresses bound to an interface, but it can be done.  (Note that you cannot just list some interfaces, as you have discovered -- either a single interface, all interfaces, or a list of IPs.)

The `-l` option can take an interface, INADDR_ANY (which means all addresses on all interfaces), or a comma separated list of IP addresses.  An IP address may have an optional port specification.  So, for instance

```
memcached -l 127.0.0.1:11211,127.0.0.1:11212,10.1.2.3
```

will have memcached listen to lo0 only on 127.0.0.1 on ports 11211 and 11212 and also to the address 10.1.2.3 (on whichever interface it is) on whatever port is set by `-p` or `-U`.

You are required to know/have all the addresses you want to bind.  This is perhaps a large gap between `lo0` and a list of IPs (since memcached's default internal resource limitations will not permit binding to the ~2^24 addresses on that interface)

Comment: Using a comma separated list of IP addresses does work. Thanks a lot! Was this feature introduced in a specific version? Because I cannot find the line "or a comma separated list of IP addresses" on any manpage.

Comment: @A.Jesin:  Poking through old configurations, this has been around since at least 2009.  Looks like a patch for multiple IPs was added in 2007 http://grokbase.com/t/danga/memcached/078qdmzphz/multiple-listen-sockets and http://lists.danga.com/pipermail/memcached/attachments/20070823/83455577/multilistensocket.obj .  It's unclear to me if this is upstream memcached or some local mods that eventually made it upstream.

Comment: @A.Jesin:  Also, don't forget that on StackExchange sites you can "accept" the answer that best works for you (so that, in the future, others having your same question will find the best answer immediately).

Comment: Interesting! This seems to have made it upstream but the version in CentOS 6.x does not yet support it.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out in the accepted answer, newer versions do support it:

```
memcached -l 127.0.0.1:11211,127.0.0.2:11211
```

or

```
memcached -l 127.0.0.1:11211 -l 127.0.0.2:11211
```

Older versions (shipped with CentOS 6.5 or earlier) do not yet support that, they can either listen on *all* interfaces, a single IP address or a socket.
Not any combination of those.

Your only way to solve this is to bind it to all interfaces and firewall the public interface or bind it to 127.0.0.1 only and forward requests to eth1:11211 to lo0:11211 via iptables.